# Display of audit log / rules fired for new business central workbench test scenario?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

One of the very useful features of the legacy Test Scenarios in Drools Workbench is the rule audit logging. This enables a lot of logic debugging which cannot be done readily in the new Test Scenarios. Is there a plan to add this capability or should we plan to rely on legacy?

Note: one of the current challenges is that the two handle Date types and other specific use cases differently / there is not full parity between the two. This creates inefficiencies in development of new rulesets which could be addressed either by fully supporting capabilities in the new Test Scenarios or by having feature parity.

Comment: both `java.util.Date` and `java.util.LocalDate` should work in new test scenarios. Could you share your use case?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that at least some of what I was looking for is contained in the Coverage Report associated with the new Test Scenarios. This report provides a list of executed rules for each test case, which is very helpful and addresses much of the need I mentioned. The issue with support for different date types remains, but I understand that is being addressed by allowing expressions in future version of test scenarios.